# IIS cant validate my client certificate

Tags: ssl, localhost, http-status-code-403, iis-8

I've tried setting up SSL for localhost running my azure web role.

What I've done is that I've created my own CA, created a client and server certificate and then installed them all in my certificate store. The server certificate is located in the local computer personal certificates, the client certificate is installed in the current user store under personal and the CA certificate is installed in trusted root certificates in both stores.

I've also configured my IIS website to use SSL and used netsh to bind the server certificate to the ip the site is running on.

However when I try to access my website through the IIS, I get an error:

```
HTTP Error 403.16 - Forbidden

Your client certificate is either not trusted or is invalid.
```

I know for a fact that the certificates I use are issued by the same CA, so I cant really see any other reason than that the IIS probably cant access my trusted root store. When I deploy my solution to azure, it works without giving me this error, so I'm positive that its a configuration issue with the local IIS that I cant work out.

Any suggestions on what could be the problem here?

Comment: I just answered this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27282889/393159